# What does shorted mean?

Tags: short-circuit

In single phase motor copper or aluminum bars are permanently shorted at both end with the help of rings. So here what does the mean of shorted?

When I am looking on Google all results are showing the meaning of short circuit. And I think both terms are different. So please help me to understand.

Answer (score 2):

This means that the aluminum or copper bars are placed in slots with the help of end rings, such that there is **permanent contact at both ends.** This means they are electrically shorted and leads to a very small resistance in the rotor.

[image]

***In response to your comments below:***

Short circuit and shorted are the same thing.

In circuit analysis, a short circuit is defined as a connection between two nodes that forces them to be at the same voltage. In the example above shorted means the bars are in contact at both ends.

Comment: Shorted means welding?

Comment: In case of aluminium squirrel cages, these are cast aluminium with the iron parts of the rotor being a part of the mould. After that, they are put on a turning machine to remove the aluminium from the girth, then they are balanced as the last step.

Comment: What is the difference b/w short circuit and shorted?

Comment: @JohnAmar, shorting does not necessarily mean welding since electrical shorting may be done in more ways than one. Short circuit and shorted are the same thing! In circuit analysis, a short circuit is defined as a connection between two nodes that forces them to be at the same voltage. In the example above shorted means the bars are in contact at both ends. This page has an examples page which may be useful. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_circuit

Comment: @JohnAmar "Shorted" is just a quicker way of writing "short circuited".  It's also easier to say!

Answer (score 1):

It is not two different terms, it is one and the same that mean the same thing.

Shorting something means that you are attempting at making a 0 Ω wire between two points. In simulations this can be done, in the real world you will always have some resistance.

A capacitor *behaves* like an open circuit if no AC is around. If there is some AC then the capacitor gradually becomes more conductive, at infinite frequency, the capacitor becomes a short. This is the basis for how a [RC filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC_circuit) works.

So if I get a wire and connect it between the terminals across a battery and the wire has:

- 0 ohm, this is a short
- 0.1 ohm, I'd still call it a short
- 1 ohm, now it starts to behave like a heating element
- 10 ohm, this will work good as a heating element

How I connect the wire doesn't matter. What kind of material it is doesn't matter. The fact that it is a *relatively* low resistance means that it is a short.

The battery has some internal resistance, and the typical value that it has (50 mΩ) is why I reasoned as above.

---

A good way to think about it is that in schematics there are wires everywhere to make it easier to show your design. If you however remove all the wires and put each element right next to each other, then you have **short**ened the distances. Your schematic still has the same functionality, every node is still there. Every branch is still there. Every wire has just been **short**ened.

---

Your **body** of several kilo Ω can *short* a lightning strike. The resistance of the air (from the cloud down to you) will be in the terra Ω range. It's all *relative*.

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed referring to electrically shorted bars. 
Re-read the operating principle of [squirrel cage induction motor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squirrel-cage_rotor#Theory)